# What would be the purpose of making a user-defined exception serializable?

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.7.2

What would be the purpose of making a user-defined exception serializable?

I am considering the use of a custom Exception class. But this is new to me, and I found the examples below at Microsoft.

The first exception class is simple, but the second one adds the `<Serializable>` attribute. What would be the purpose of this?

[How To Create User-Defined Exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-create-user-defined-exceptions)

```
Public Class EmployeeListNotFoundException
    Inherits Exception

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(message As String)
        MyBase.New(message)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(message As String, inner As Exception)
        MyBase.New(message, inner)
    End Sub
End Class
```

[How To Create User-Defined Exceptions With Localized Exception Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-create-localized-exception-messages)

```
<Serializable>
Public Class StudentNotFoundException
    Inherits Exception

    Public ReadOnly Property StudentName As String

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(message As String)
        MyBase.New(message)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(message As String, inner As Exception)
        MyBase.New(message, inner)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(message As String, studentName As String)
        Me.New(message)
        StudentName = studentName
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: That was important back in the days that AppDomains were still considered useful.  Only serializable exceptions can be passed from crashing code in a dedicated appdomain to controlling code in the main appdomain.  That never really worked out, support for custom appdomains was removed from .NET Core.  So no longer any real point in having to do this.

Comment: @HansPassant ok, thanks. I assumed it had something to do with remoting, of something where exceptions could be passed between systems (all of which I'm not familiar with). I'm also not familiar with .Net Core. The work I do is the version we have installed, which is .Net Framework 4.7.2. So it sounds like I can safely ditch the serializable attribute..?

Comment: It is not called .NET Core anymore, at version 5 they renamed it to .net5.  Currently at .net8.  Sooner or later you'll use it.